# pywinauto detect if dynamic control exists

Tags: python, exists, pywinauto

I'm trying automate the standard Camera app in windows with pywinauto.

I can successfully call clicks etc on controls that exist, but the camera app dynamically switches capture buttons when it switches from Photo to video so I need to detect which mode it's in.

```
from subprocess import Popen
from pywinauto import Desktop
from pywinauto.application import Application

# ====== Take a Photo =======
# Need to get at the Camera app from desktop as there's multiple processes in the UI
dlg = Desktop(backend="uia").Camera
dlgWin = dlg.child_window(title="Camera", class_name="Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow")

# This fails:
#existFlag = dlgWin.child_window(title="Take Photo", control_type="Button").Exists(timeout =2) 

# Take photo, this works if the control exists:
buttonTakePhoto = dlgWin.child_window(title="Take Photo", control_type="Button")
buttonTakePhoto.click()
```

Here's the control structure when in Photo mode:

[image]

And in Video mode:

[image]

How do I detect if a child control of a window exists?  All the examples I've seen use an app instance which I don't have since I get the window as a child of the Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I swear I tried this, but it works:

buttonTakePhoto.exists()

Comment: Default timeout is 5 sec. So timeout=2 may not work since it still doesn't exist after 2 sec. But I'd recommend `buttonTakePhoto.wait('visible', timeout=5)` instead of `.exists()`.